# Unable to open spreadsheets downloaded from reports

Tags: reporting, data-export

This could be a Salesforce problem or an Office problem although I am leaning toward the former rather than the latter.

When we Export Details from reports, there are a number of users who're struggling to open these files. Excel opens, albeit blank like below:

[image]

What's odd is that if we e-mail the exact same file to ourselves, the document will then open.

If the file is exported as a .csv file, it opens as expected.

Has anyone else experienced this bug? Is this likely to even be a Salesforce bug or something to do with Office instead?

**Edit**

- This happens regardless of the user opening directly from the browser or directly accessing the file from folders
- It happens regardless of Excel being open at the time or not, with or without Spreadsheets being open
- This is happening on multiple PCs with multiple users with various profiles (including System Administrator) on Salesforce

Comment: I've never heard of this happening before, so I'd highly assume this is an issue with the PC or office setup.  That's just a guess though.  Does the same thing happen if the user downloads the file (rather than open directly in excel) and then opens the file from their PC?  Does the user already have excel open?  Perhaps with other spreadsheets open?  This is troubleshooting 101.

Comment: @NickCook See my edits. It may well be an Office problem, but was curious to know if this was a Salesforce issue as the initial file downloaded doesn't work, but when sent through Outlook (and is "processed" from there) to the user it opens.

Comment: Take a look at what Security Updates you have installed for Excel, specifically as outlined here: [End user cannot open a .xls report exported from Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131404/end-user-cannot-open-a-xls-report-exported-from-salesforce)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Perfect! Thanks Adrian I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. If you write this as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what Security Updates you have installed for Excel, specifically as outlined here: [End user cannot open a .xls report exported from Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131404/end-user-cannot-open-a-xls-report-exported-from-salesforce).