# End user cannot open a .xls report exported from Salesforce KB3115455

Tags: reporting, excel

Again we are back at ... Removing KB3115455 will resolve this issue. I thought SalesForce fixed this, but appears Microsoft fixed it as well and both solutions are causing the same issue as KB3115262. Can we get these ducks in a row with either one ...

Comment: Is this really a different question than [End user cannot open a .xls report exported from Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131404/end-user-cannot-open-a-xls-report-exported-from-salesforce)?

Comment: Not really a different question another issue that came out today. Different Windows Update KB3115262 caused the same behavior as we are seeing in KB3115455. Microsoft patched the issues with this update "KB3115455" but with SalesForce developers fixing the issue on their own, Microsoft fixed it as well and appears to cause a "Corrupted" error pop up. So we are back at square one again. I'm letting everyone know that there is an issue again and what Windows Update is responsible for it. I could not reply to that post because I just created an account so was stuck opening another one.

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Currently we have KB3115262 removed from customers computers and with the new update KB3115455 installed as of 8/9/16 update it is producing a "Corrupted" error when running reports in SalesForce. I removed KB3115455 from the system and was able to successfully run the report and open without errors.

Comment: Why is this being marked as duplicate. It is not a duplicate issue. With KB3115455 being released its causing a corrupted error when running a report. It spins off of the issue with KB3115262 as specified in the "So Called" duplicate. But, still this issue is a separate from the previous one. I am trying to make others aware of the patch that is causing the "Corrupt" prompt. KB3115262 did not launch an error from Excel and say the file was Corrupt. It simply just did not open the file and you would sit at a blank Excel screen.